# min-width on a three column absolute positioned layout

Tags: html, layout, css

My current layout is based on this:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/body5.html

It involves three columns which are each independently scrollable and fluid. However my web app can only shrink in width so much, and at a certain point I would like for something like a min-width (where they will have to scroll horizontally to experience the site)

I tried putting a min-width on the body, but that did absolutely nothing. I also tried wrapping the columns in a containing div and giving it a min-width, this also did not work.

Does anyone else have any ideas on how to approach this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm basing my answer on the link you provided.

On `html` and `body`, remove `overflow:hidden`.

On `body`, add `position:relative; min-width:960px`.

Tested in recent versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

This also works in IE7+ if you remove the comment at the top `<!-- IE into quirks mode -->`.

Comment: Works very well, just one question. Is it possible to have the x-axis scrollbar only appear when necessary in firefox. It seems to be there even if my page is wider than the min-width

Comment: I can't reproduce that on the linked page with my changes applied in any of Firefox versions 6, 3.6, 9.0a1. Can you show me what you have so far using [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: It's the `input` inside `.discussion-box`. A simple fix is to add `overflow: hidden` to `#right .discussion-box`.